# Maven command line throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on adding Avro dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, avro

I'm new to Maven and installed 3.5.0 in Windows 64 bit machine. I have added Avro dependency in `pom.xml` as specified in https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedjava.html. I am facing Build failure and getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when doing `mvn clean compile` from the command line:

```
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.147 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-29T10:56:16-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 53090
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 53090
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502
)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:
1604)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:143
4)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.j
ava:3856)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.j
ava:595)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.
java:109)
        at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.
java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultMod
elProcessor.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(Default
ModelBuilder.java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExterna
lly(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1097)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(Defaul
tModelBuilder.java:829)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultMode
lBuilder.java:331)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:321)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.
readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCa
chedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifa
ctDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(D
efaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse
(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:513)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDe
pendency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(D
efaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDe
pendencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDepen
dencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(D
efaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDe
pendencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resol
veProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAr
eResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
356)
[ERROR]
```

Below is the `pom.xml` file which I am using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Trail</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>  
          <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>junit</groupId>
                      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                      <version>3.8.1</version>
                      <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
          </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add the maven log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6216 for all the details.

In short: while downloading the pom, the file got corrupt. For some reason extra content is added after the closing tag, making it not a valid xml file. Maven 3.3.9 and before ignored all data afterwards, 3.5.0 is more strict. There are 2 simple solutions: remove your local repository or use maven 3.3.9

Where's still looking for the cause of this issue. It is probably there for a long time but it was never an issue.

You could check the pom of avro, because that one is causing the issue or one of its dependencies.