# Maven build process ERROR involve with Anypoint Studio configuration (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15469)

Tags: java, xml, maven, anypoint-studio

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15469
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2502)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1604)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1434)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1131)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3856)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:595)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader.read(DefaultModelReader.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor.read(DefaultModelProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:275)
    at
```

Hi, I have problem with the above error. I paste logs form my Anypoint's console. 
I think that it is problem w configuration of Anypoint Studio and build maven process. As f1sh mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: This seems to happen inside the maven build process, so it's not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue on this post: [Maven command line throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on adding Avro dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830273/maven-command-line-throwing-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-on-adding-avro-depend)

> See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6216 for all the
>   details.
>
> In short: while downloading the pom, the file got corrupt. For some
>   reason extra content is added after the closing tag, making it not a
>   valid xml file. Maven 3.3.9 and before ignored all data afterwards,
>   3.5.0 is more strict. There are 2 simple solutions: remove your local repository or use maven 3.3.9

Comment: I install version 3.3.9 and error disapeared. Thanks @Pierre B.